# Write metric in term of wedge product

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors, exterior-algebra

This is an introductory question. I am bit confused how to write the Euclidean metric for example $$ds^2=dx^2+dy^2$$ in term of the wedge product?

This is two form and hence can be written in term of wedge of two one forms. One way to write using the outer product
$$g_{\mu\nu}(dx^\mu \otimes dx^\nu)$$ But since $\wedge$ and $\otimes$ are related I should be able to write in term of the $\wedge$ but $$dx\wedge dx=0$$

Comment: Linear combinations of wedge products yield alternating tensors. However the metric tensor is  symmetric. The only tensor which is both is the zero tensor (which the metric tensor is not).

Comment: Does it mean we can not write symmetric tensors in term of wedge product

Comment: That is correct, you cannot write symmetric tensors as linear combinations of the wedge product

Comment: Geometrically $dx\wedge dy$ measures a tiny surface. As we know however, the metric $g$ measures the length of tiny lines. To be precise $g$ measures length-squared.

Comment: Differential forms are tensors, but tensors need not be differential forms.

Comment: $dx\otimes dx\neq dx\wedge dx$

Answer (score 3):

This question is really about linear algebra, since the issue is visible separately on each tangent space.

It follows from the definition that linear combinations of wedge products are alternating tensors:
$$(\alpha \wedge \beta)(X, Y) = \alpha(X) \beta(Y) - \beta(x) \alpha(Y) = -(\alpha \wedge \beta)(Y, X),$$
so for any $2$-form $\omega := \sum_i \alpha_i \wedge \beta_i$, $$\omega(X, Y) = -\omega(Y, X).$$ In particular, for any $X$, $$\omega(X, X) = 0 .$$

On the other hand, a Riemannian metric is a symmetric tensor: $$g(X, Y) = g(Y, X) .$$ So, if $g$ were a linear combination of wedge products, we would have for all $X, Y$ that $g(X, Y) = -g(Y, X) = -g(X, Y)$, hence $g = 0$, a contradiction (unless the manifold has dimension $0$).